# Find ping response interface via java or linux

Tags: java, linux, ping, network-interface

In a Multi homed machine ( multiple network interfaces and hence may have multiple IP addresses ), Using Java / Linux base ping finding which interface is actually returning the ping response as the ping is sent to all available interfaces.

One way i figured of is to use the -I and set the source interface to force ping via one interface but in case of 3 or more hybrid NIC cases we may have to deal with many pings to zero in on the correct interface.

Any direct / easier suggestions?

Comment: You want to know from Java which NIC did response a ping request ?

Comment: Huh? The `-s`? The `-s` option of Linux `ping` sets the packet size. Also where are you pinging from? What exactly are you trying to find out about the interface (it's IP? it's MAC?) What have you tried? How do your expected results differ from your actual and where is your code? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @JasonC my mistake , the option is -I. I was trying ping -I eth1 google.com , this basically routes the pings via the interface.

Comment: @PeterMmm Its needed in a monitoring suite. Need not be a java code , its can still be sand witched via a script. I know its its not a great idea to do the NIC operations in the Java, but thats how it is...

Comment: Still totally unclear what you are asking. Are you saying that you are attempting to find which local interface is responsible for communicating with some given remote host?

Comment: @JasonC your answer was spot on... I am actually trying to find which local interface among many is responsible for the communication. Wish I had more reputation to thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is determine which interface is used to get to a given destination (from https://serverfault.com/questions/188597/how-to-see-on-linux-what-network-interface-and-source-ip-address-is-used-for-a-r), parse the output of:

```
ip route get <destination_ip>
```

The interface printed there will be the same one that receives a ping response when you ping `<destination_ip>`.

This only works on Linux. There may be an equivalent Windows command. I don't know.

Comment: Just tested the command in the production and it works like a charm. Owe you a beer buddy!!

Answer (score 0):

For script on Linux you can apply an [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/) rule to log if a ping request is received on a certain interface. Afterwards or while logging you can process the log file to get out the NIC information.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/

Comment: Thanks, i think ip route get may give a simple solution if there is only one ip to ping . Yours will help in case of multi- device ping where in we can ping and finally get the log file and analyze all ...